# How to properly(independently) include files

Tags: php

So basically I'm trying to include files in an independent(from where I include it) way and I'm getting a hard time figuring how I really should to it in terms of good architecture etc.

I've tried something like this:

public_html/functions/functions.php:

```
function load_header() {
   include( get_path() . 'load/header.php' );
}
function get_path() {
   return 'https://example.com/';
}
```

public_html/index.php:

```
include('functions/functions.php');
$path = get_path();
load_header();
```

public_html/load/header.php:

```
// code
// using variable $path inside of it
// code
```

The problem with the above code is... everything, really. I can't get access to the $path and what not.

Is there some well-known-way to handle something like this? I'm sure there must be something... I don't want to use any frameworks or anything like that.

Hope for your help, Thanks

Comment: Forget the inclusion nonsense. Use autoloader. Preferably composer and psr-4. Avoid PHP files with side effects as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it as parameters. Had you done this without the functions, there would be no problems, e.g.

```
# file1.php
$test = 'hello, world';

# file2.php
include 'file1.php';
echo $test;
```

works, but due to function scope, you don't have access to the `$test` variable.

Pass it to the function via parameters:

```
function load_header($path)
{
    include(get_path(). 'load/header.php');
}
```

now inside `header.php` you have `$path`.